# Use Excel to automate Selenium test in Apache POI

Tags: selenium, automation, katalon-studio

I am a complete beginner in Selenium and I am not able to automate the Selenium code below. I have tried numerous methods but I am still getting issues with automating the run from getting the data from excel. I have even tried using the TestNG method as well but no luck I am stuck on this part not. Can someone help on how to automate this code without changing the row numbers in this step `for (int i= 1; i<=noOfRows ; i++)`.
The code used:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    System.setProperty("driver location");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("link");


    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("xcel file location");

    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
    XSSFSheet sheet= workbook.getSheet("SO Reg");

    int noOfRows = sheet.getLastRowNum(); // returns the row count
    System.out.println("No. of Records in the Excel Sheet:" + noOfRows);

    int cols=sheet.getRow(1).getLastCellNum();  
    System.out.println("No. of Records in the Excel Sheet:" + cols);

    for (int i= 1; i<=6; i++)
    {
                String SO_Name = row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
                String Contact_Person = row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
                String Address_1 = row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
                String Address_2 = row.getCell(3).getStringCellValue();
                String City = row.getCell(4).getStringCellValue();
                String State = row.getCell(5).getStringCellValue();
                String ZipCode = row.getCell(6).getStringCellValue();
                String Phone_Number = row.getCell(8).getStringCellValue();
                String Username = row.getCell(9).getStringCellValue();
                String Email = row.getCell(10).getStringCellValue();
                String Re_Type_Email = row.getCell(11).getStringCellValue();

                //Registration Process

                driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("p.text-white:nth-child(4) > a:nth-child(1)")).click(); //create an account
                Thread.sleep(5000); 

                //Enter Data information

                driver.findElement(By.id("SOName")).sendKeys(SO_Name);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ContactPerson\"]")).sendKeys(Contact_Person);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"AddressLine1\"]")).sendKeys(Address_1);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"AddressLine2\"]")).sendKeys(Address_2);
                driver.findElement(By.id("City")).sendKeys(City);
                driver.findElement(By.id("State")).sendKeys(State);
                driver.findElement(By.id("ZipCode")).sendKeys(ZipCode);
                driver.findElement(By.id("Phone")).sendKeys(Phone_Number);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"UserName\"]")).sendKeys(Username);       
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"Email\"]")).sendKeys(Email);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"RandText\"]")).sendKeys(Re_Type_Email);
                driver.findElement(By.id("ConfirmBox")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/app-soregistration/div[2]/div/div/div/div/form[2]/div/div[12]/div/button[1]")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn-green-text-black")).click(); //finish button


                driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("p.text-white:nth-child(4) > a:nth-child(1)")).click(); //create an account
                Thread.sleep(5000); 
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

java
selenium
automation
katalon-studio

Comment: Code looks clean. What is the issue?

Comment: Not able to use for multiple runs using a .XLSX file. For eg, if i have to run 15 tests continuously then i have to change the number one by one here : "for (int i= 1; i<=6; i++)" I have to change the int i value for each run. But my question is how do I automate it without changing the int value each time for a new row.

Comment: I still don't understand. In the `for` block there is no `i` usage. Btw where comes `row` objet from?

Comment: In this line for (int i= 1; i<=6; i++) the row object. the value of i=1 is the data from excel. So if I change it to 2 and then run it produces the new set of data provided in excel file. I want is to run it automatically and not change the i value each time.

Comment: Then you have to create the data set before the main method and use the data set as argument.